# Avoiding CPU Contention

Tags: c++, cpu, average, c++-chrono

I have a program that I want to calculate its time of execution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{


     boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Intructions to burn time 

    boost::chrono::duration<double> sec = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    cout <<"---- time execution is " << sec.count() << ";";
    return 0;
}
```

For example the result after one run:

---- time execution is 0.0223588

This result isn't very conscious because the CPU time is included .

I had An idea to avoid CPU contention by testing many runs and getting there average .

The problem is :

- How can I store the time value of the previous run ?
- Can we do that via a file ?
- How to incrementally calculate the average after each run ?

Your suggestion / pseudocodes are welcome.

Comment: If you are using a unix operating system and bash as your shell you could invoke your program as `time ./[progexe]` and use the sys time output of that as the cputime of the program.

Comment: This question is remarkably broad, boiling down to "how do I properly construct benchmarks?" and I'm not satisfied that you've done any notable research on the topic yet.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, that's the question that should have been asked.  The questions actually asked, concerning averaging results across runs, is a much more appropriate scope.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit why are you considering this question is out of scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass average number via command line using 2 args: current average value and the number of iterations performed.
Then:
NewAverage = ((CurrentAverage*N) + CurrentValue) / (N+1);
where N is the number of iterations.